# Can I merge these two Sql Server index into one:

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Sql server 2022 with more tahn 100 milion records, Can I merge these two index into one:

```
create nonclustered index [IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendStatus] on [dbo].[SMSInOutBoxDetails]
    (
     [SMSInOutBox_ID] asc,
     [SendStatus] asc
        )
    include ([Cost]) on [PRIMARY]
```

```
create nonclustered index [IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendTime] on [dbo].[SMSInOutBoxDetails]
    (
     [SMSInOutBox_ID] asc,
     [SendTime] asc
        )
    include ([ID], [Number], [Delivery], [Cost], [RefId], [SendStatus], [IsRead], [MobileOperator],
             [WebServiceOutboxDetailId], [Order],
             [sort]) on [PRIMARY]
```

Merge Index:

```
create nonclustered index [IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendStatus_SendTime] on [dbo].[SMSInOutBoxDetails]
    (
     [SMSInOutBox_ID] asc,
     [SendStatus] asc,
     [SendTime] asc
        )
    include ([ID], [Number], [Delivery], [Cost], [RefId], [IsRead], [MobileOperator], [WebServiceOutboxDetailId],
             [Order], [sort])
    on [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge them into one"? They're ordered on different columns, and we've no knowledge of what types of queries you use against the table. Not to mention the `INCLUDE` clauses are wildly different.

Comment: @ThomA please see that update, I need merge one for less index for better performance

Comment: That Index will provide a similar "service" to `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendStatus` but *not* to `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendStatus_SendTime`; so if you frequently query by time, but not status, that index may not help you.

Comment: I *assume* that `SMSInOutBox_ID` isn't a unique identifying in your table `SMSInOutBoxDetails`, by the way?

Comment: Yeah It's not unique, It's parent record reference

Comment: You need to identify the queries you currently have that are using these indexes and see how they are using them. Depending on how `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendTime` is being used then potentially your new index could somewhat replace the functionality of it on the assumption that there aren't many `SendStatus` but this would need a query rewrite and not happen automatically (and still mean fanning out what used to be a single seek to become multiple seeks)

Comment: So I need to use query hints, right?

Comment: No - it would be a  query rewrite if the new index is even suitable at all. Which we don't know as we have no idea what queries you have that use each index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an automatic quick win merge candidate. When you try to combine them you need to select whether to go for

`[SMSInOutBox_ID], [SendStatus], [SendTime]` or for `[SMSInOutBox_ID], [SendTime], [SendStatus]`.

Your proposed index will support a superset of the queries that `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendStatus` does (though maybe at the expense of some logical reads as it won't be as compact as the existing one).

But it won't support all the queries that `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendTime` does.

For example if you have a query

```
SELECT SMSInOutBox_ID,
       SendStatus,
       Cost,
       SendTime,
       ID,
       Number,
       Delivery,
       RefId,
       IsRead,
       MobileOperator,
       WebServiceOutboxDetailId,
       [Order],
       sort
FROM   dbo.SMSInOutBoxDetails
WHERE  [SMSInOutBox_ID] = @SMSInOutBox_ID
       AND [SendTime] > @SendTime
ORDER  BY [SendTime]
```

Then `IX_SMSInOutBoxDetails_SMSInOutBox_ID_SendTime` will support returning this from a single index seek without any sort operations.

If you only have a limited number of send statuses though (maybe Delivered, Sent, Rejected and Failed?) your new index could still support this but it is more cumbersome (and also runs a risk that new statuses might be added without being reflected here)

```
    WITH T AS
    (
    SELECT SMSInOutBox_ID,
           SendStatus,
           Cost,
           SendTime,
           ID,
           Number,
           Delivery,
           RefId,
           IsRead,
           MobileOperator,
           WebServiceOutboxDetailId,
           [Order],
           sort
    FROM   dbo.SMSInOutBoxDetails
    WHERE  [SMSInOutBox_ID] = @SMSInOutBox_ID
               AND [SendTime] > @SendTime
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM T
   WHERE SendStatus = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM T
   WHERE SendStatus = 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM T
   WHERE SendStatus = 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM T
   WHERE SendStatus = 4
   ORDER BY SendTime, ID /*I have assumed ID is a clustered primary key here*/
```

The above does 4 independent index seeks that will bring back the rows in order of `SendTime, RowLocator` and combines them with a merge union to bring back the global resultset without any sorting ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TGyhVdZb)).

[image]